# How to read header and footer child elements in sequence order using word interop C#

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

We are working with forms and in current project we are working with NPOI object but due to word metadata npoi is not returning the first,even and odd page Headers/footers. So we are trying with interop for getting the correct results and we are able to get the results as per the below code. But again we are facing the challenge with reading bodyelements in sequence order which are under headers/footers.

**Current Result:**
I am able to read the body elements(table and paragraph) of header/footer. But not in sequence order. I can able to read the elements individually like "firstPageFooter .Paragraphs" and "firstPageFooter .Tables"

```
foreach (Section data in sections)
{
    var tempVal = string.Empty;
    HeadersFooters headersFooters = data.Footers;
    bool isDifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = Convert.ToBoolean(data.PageSetup.DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter);

    bool isOddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = Convert.ToBoolean(data.PageSetup.OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter);

    if (isDifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter)
        firstPageFooter = headersFooters[WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterFirstPage].Range;

    Tables headerTable = firstPageFooter .Tables;

    StringBuilder tableBuilder = new StringBuilder();                    

    foreach (Table table in headerTable)
    {
        foreach (Row row in table.Rows)
        {
            foreach (Cell cell in row.Cells)
            {
                tableBuilder.Append(cell.Range.Text);
            }
        }
    }

    StringBuilder paraBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    var headerPara= firstPageFooter.Paragraphs;

    foreach (Paragraph paragraph in headerPara)
    {
        paraBuilder.Append(paragraph.Range.Text);
    }
}   // Added by edit!!!
```

**Expected Results:**
If the header/Footer body elements contains tables and paragraph. First element is table and second is paragraph. So the word should return the body elements in the same sequence order.

Can some one help me out?

Comment: This isn't really terribly clear. I *think* I understand, but it would help if you could use the [edit] link to include a small example of what you mean (both source and expected result). According to what I understand based on the question, if you loop the `Paragraphs` collection and *test* each paragraph (for example, whether it's in a table) you should be able to work from there.

Comment: Thanks for the update Cindy. Sorry for the incomplete details. I have updated my issue hope it will be clear.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to loop the `Paragraphs` collection of the document `Story` (a Header, for example) and test whether it's in a table. If it is, then pick up the table and process it. Then continue with the paragraph below the table, until the `Story` has been completed.

Here's a code snippet that demonstrates this approach, based on a single Header.

```
Word.HeaderFooter hdr = doc.Sections[1].Headers[Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary];
Word.Range hdrRange = hdr.Range;
Word.Paragraphs paras = hdrRange.Paragraphs;
for (int counter = 1; counter <= paras.Count; counter++)
{
    Word.Paragraph para = paras[counter];
    if ((bool)para.Range.get_Information(Word.WdInformation.wdWithInTable))
    {
        //Get the table that belongs to the first paragraph in the table
        Word.Table tbl = para.Range.Tables[1];
        //Reset the counter so that it cycles to the paragraph after the table
        counter += tbl.Range.Paragraphs.Count - 1;
        Debug.Print("In table with " + (counter - 1).ToString() + " paragraphs");
        //Process the table
    }
    else
    {
        //Process the paragraph
        Debug.Print("Paragraph " + counter.ToString() + ": " + para.Range.Text);
    }
}
```

Comment: If i am not wrong this approach works if the table is in paragraph but what if the two elements are placed one after another? How do we loop through the body elements in sequence order? We have a forms which contains table and paragraph one after another in headers.  Ex: Table has two rows and two columns and paragraph is placed after the table.

Comment: @LalithaRani: What you ask in the comment is not clear. My answer bases purely on the information provided in the content. A table cannot be "in" a paragraph. What could possibly be "one after the other" *horizontally*? The code in the question handles tables and paragraphs as separate entities. The code in the answer will handles tables and paragraphs *vertically*. Did you actually *TRY* it?

Comment: yes the two elements are placed horizontally. I tried the above code and it returns everything. But we are looking for the solution like the object should return the list of child elements like npoi object does. Ex: Npoi object return the list of child elements of a header  "var firstPageHeader = policy.GetFirstPageHeader().BodyElements" it return the list of bodyelements of a headers

Comment: @LalithaRani Tables and paragraphs cannot be positioned horizontally next to each other - unless they're in `Shape` object (text wrap formattng applied). It^s next to impossible, using the interop, to get the order of things as they appear in the underlying Word Open XML as the interop is layout-based : the UI interpretation of the XML. Have you tried `firstPageFooter.WordOpenXML` then parsed that? It sounds as if that might be what you need...

Comment: I haven't tried this firstPageFooter.WordOpenXML. I don't have idea on it. Can you help me on this?

Comment: @LalithaRani This returns the Word Open XML *as a string* that defines the `Range` object on which it's executed - in the OPC flat file format (research that). It's possible to parse that "as is", or convert it to a "zip package" that can be read by a library, for example the Open XML SDK.

Comment: Sure Cindy i will try this. Thanks for the help